# C++ Template mechanics

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to learn templates in c++ and i came across with a doubt that i can't find answers for. I'm sorry in advance if this is not a proper question.

If i have the following code:

```
template< class T >
T func( T a, T b )
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And then:

```
int number = func( 2, 3 );
```

Will number simply be set to 5 or will a function

```
int func( int a, int b )
{
    return a + b;
}
```

be generated?

I need to know if i can make a template that checks if a certain string is in a file.

Comment: Function templates are used to stamp out functions.

Comment: Your question really should end with "... or both?"

Comment: How can the difference, if any, affect your code?

Comment: It's different if it sets the value to 5 in compile time rather than generating the function to set it in run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both (: The code:

```
int number = func( 2, 3 );
```

will instantiate the template function for int type, but compiler may (depending on compiler options) actually optimize it to just:

```
int number = 5;
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer i needed to know what exacly i could do with templates. I found that giving use to templates is harder than actualy learning them...

Comment: Once you start to write same code but for different types, that's a good candidate to convert your code to a template.

Comment: @BisaZ would you like to mark this question as "correct"?  :)  That will let people know that this has been resolved.

Comment: Done sorry i did not do it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

A function equivalent to

```
int func( int a, int b )
{
    return a + b;
}
```

will certainly be generated (unless, of course, it's optimized out). To see this, try

```
int (*func_int)(int, int) = func<int>; // pointer to instantiated function
int number = func_int(2, 3); // sets number to 5
```